# new Android Studio update [0.5.0]

Tags: java, android-studio, manifest

A couple of days a ago a new Android Studio update was released. I installed it, and since then nothing seems to work. Everything worked fine before, but now I get a couple of errors.

Especially in the Manifest

```xml
<application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
         android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
         <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.3"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_3" >
    </activity>`
```

Every `com.example.app` is marked red with the error

> com.example.app.xxxxx' is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity'

When I try to start my app a red box tells me the following:

> Error running app: Gradle profect sync failed. Please fix your profect and try again.

But how can I fix my project? I really don't want to start from the beginning - I am nearly finished ...

build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'android'

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 19
     buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 9
         targetSdkVersion 16
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             runProguard false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
         }
     }
 }

 dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
 }
```

EDIT :

I don't know why, but the SO editor isn't showing the full code I wanted to post correctly ....

Comment: Post your Build.gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 0.5.0 requires the 0.9.0 gradle plugin. Have you updated that as well?

Comment: Increment the version in your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file.